product category premade dataset
I am working on a e-commerce website, where I need to create a product-category table while having all possible categories & sub-categories up to level 5 predefined. for example:
Beauty > Men's Care > Shaving & Grooming > Shaving Accessories
main category is Beauty, after that sub-category Men's Care to Shaving Accessories. each level category connected to their upper level category using "parent_id" & "level".
since it is an multi vendor e-commerce website, all the categories need to be pre-defined. and creating such dataset looks like a very big task.
so I was wondering if somebody else created such dataset earlier, and if i could download and use that. I am looking in the internet, but could not find anything. anyway, if still cannot find i will start making it.
thank you

I am creating a universal ecommerce category datasheet.
here is the link category-datasheet
It will have maximum of 5 level, trying to keep it up to level 4.
Initially making it in google sheet so that later I can save as csv file in order to upload in mysql database.
Every entry must have an unique id.

Level one ID : first 3 digit [starting form 100]
Level two ID : 2 digit [starting form 10]
Level three ID : 2 digit [starting form 10]
Level four ID : 2 digit [starting form 10]
Level five ID : 2 digit [starting form 10]

level one will not have any parent_id so "null"
level two - five must have the parent_id.
If anybody want to contribute in this list, please open the link and ask for editing access. after that create a sheet using ur name.
I want to keep the datasheet open for anybody to use.
